# How to open SMS (Messaging client) application in a separate instance (like Gmail)?

Tags: android, android-intent, webview, gmail, sms

I have a html page to open in `WebView`, on this html page I have two `Buttons`-

1. To open GMail app
2. To open SMS app

I am using following code to open particular application-

```
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
```

The problem is, when I click on GMail icon, GMail app is opening with separate instance but SMS app is opening on the same instance of our main application.

Please help to open SMS app same as GMail app (SMS app should be open separately as GMail app does).

Comment: Add `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)`.

Comment: I also added it, but no luck. Actually SMS app is opening as new application but when I come back to my app using Overview button, SMS app not existing anymore (killing itself). I want SMS app should visible on tray after I come back to my application using Overview button as GMail behavior.

Comment: What is Overview button? The recent App button ?

Comment: Yes, It is recent app button.